Some of the import modules are not working as expected
I'm training a tensorflow AI to from a stupid AI with fresh neural networks to a actual physicist.
Some of the import modules are not working as expected:
I get these following errors:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text could not be resolved.
Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
What can I do?
I tried various methods I saw in other stackoverflow discussions however once I ran, I recieved this:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\O\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main return _run_code(code, main_globals, None, File "C:\Users\O\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\Users\O\Desktop\ultiamte_ai_system\data\preprocess.py", line 4, in <module> from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
My python interperter is 3.11.3 local.

The traceback shows your python is 3.10, not 3.11. That (and the linter's errors quoted first) suggest that your IDE is configured to use different interpreter than you thought - find Interpreter Settings in your IDE and set it to correct python (the 3.11 you want and probably installed tf in there already)
